# When (and how often) is $2^k+1$ a prime power?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Fermat proved that [if $N = 2^k+1$ is prime, then $k=2^n$ for some $n \geqslant 0$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Other_theorems_about_Fermat_numbers). In this case $N$ is known as a [Fermat prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number). Only five known Fermat primes exist, corresponding to $n \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$, and it is thought that perhaps these are the only ones which exist.

Are there any results known for when $N = 2^k+1$ is a *power of* a prime? A simple application: are there infinitely many finite fields which have the property that all of their units are $2^k$th roots of unity?

Comment: Please look at Wikipedia, Catalan Conjecture, now a theorem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Catalan's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture) (now a theorem, proven in 2002 by Preda Mihăilescu), the only two non-trivial consecutive perfect powers (numbers $x^a$ and $y^b$ for integers $x,y,a,b > 1$) are 8 and 9. It follows that $N = 2^k + 1$ is a prime power only if $N = 9$ or $N$ is itself a (Fermat) prime.